# JWPlayer - show many ads using VAST

Tags: video, jwplayer, ads, vast

I need the following thing: JWPlayer which shows only VAST ads, with no real videos, only video ads. I want them to automatically play one by one all the time, so when the first one ends, another starts, then third one. Is that possible to do with JWPlayer? If another player supports that, could you suggest the player? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, with an ad schedule, in JW Player 6 - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31404/ad-scheduling

Comment: Thanks! But I don't see ads in the video from your link. I see only a video of rabbit, no ads. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Europe, Ukraine, Ternopil city

Comment: Also I asked a friend of mine from Boston, US to test. He watched one video ad, then he had to click the play button again to see one more ad.

Comment: What can be the problem? In ad servers?

Comment: No issues. On this page, it shows a preroll, then an overlay in 15 seconds. No 2nd click required. - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31404/ad-scheduling, you are probably not seeing ads because they are geo targeted. I am located in NYC.

Comment: A friend of mine from Bethlehem, PA has just tried. It showed him video ad in the beginning, then showed video with rabbit and no ads after that. One more question: is that possible to remove "you will be able to skip the ad in xx seconds" text? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45411/discussion-between-volodymyr-and-ethan-jwplayer)

Comment: He did not get an overlay ad at 15 seconds? You can remove that - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28862/configuring-video-ads, please contact us here - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/